# VBA Excel match A with either column D or E if first three letters match otherwise write "there"

Tags: excel, counter, contentoffset, vba

On non-vba excel, I was trying to use this equation:

```
=IF(LEFT($A1,4)=LEFT($C1,4), VLOOKUP((LEFT($A1,4)&"*"),C1:C1,1,FALSE), "there")
```

but it is not always accurate because it is not offsetting when the word "there" used on the cell.

I need it to:

1. Look at the first three letters of Column A and match them to Column C.
2. Copy the contents of column C into Column B or if it is not a match then write "there".
3. Then go to the next empty cell look at the first three letters of column A and match them to the next set on column C.

I think I have to do a counter for both column A and column C but then I get lost.

Any help with this will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the below formula in column B, [LEFT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c)

```
=IF(LEFT($A1,3)=LEFT($C1,3),$C1,"there")
```

Hope this is what you are expecting